# Is it possible to change variable from view in JavaScript? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create some var in my JADE view in Node.js application, for example:

```
- var MyVariable = ''
```

And when i click on the button:

```
button(onclick="show('#{item._id}')")
```

I want to change `MyVariable` to value of `item._id`

```
function show(partner_id){
        MyVariable = partner_id
        }
```

Unfortunately, the code above won't work

Comment: That doesn't seem to be valid Jade tag definition. Why are using a dot there?

Comment: Because of: `- each item in partnerList` before. It's in loop

Comment: I was referring to this dot: `button.(onclick...`

Comment: No, it's still a syntax error.

Comment: Button is a CSS class. Btw that's not the point of this question.

Comment: Templates are evaluated on the server. Client side JS is evaluated on the client side.

Comment: Your jade view should call a JS file that handles this stuff. As dave said, tempates are evaluated on the server. Put a script tag in, and call a JS sheet with event delegation or an event listener that looks for that button click and gets the value of the ID.

Answer (score -1):

Where are you passing `item` to the jade template? You should be able to simply assign `MyVariable` in the same place.

Comment: I want to assign only after clicking on the button.